# What is the difference between akh and ekha

Tags: hebrew

For example, retsonekha, retsonakh. Kodsheha, kodshakh. What is the reason for this difference?

I see this difference in several places in the jewish prayer books, for example in Yedid Nefesh or in the Kedusha. This is why I am asking it through this website.

Comment: I just edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

-*kha* is masculine. -*kh* is generally (though not always) feminine.

Comment: Thanks but sometimes in the KedushaI hear Kodshakh and it is not feminine. Same in Yedid Nefesh.

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: @far22 it's a good question! Aramaic and some later dialects of Hebrew appear to use "ach" for addressing the masculine. For those siddurs that use "Naaritzach" rather than "Naaritzcha", it's not clear whether we sometimes feel that feminine is the better form for addressing G-d (who has no gender really, it's about what traditional gender model best describes whatever G-d's doing right now); or if it was simply using a different dialect for the masculine.